# An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: -author

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, maven

Hi am facing some maven plugin issues, when am trying to deploy java-webservices project, My project was not downloading `"maven-javadoc-plugin : 2.4"` plugins, I manually installed `"maven-javadoc-plugin 2.5"` version jar into my .m2/repository. Am getting

```
"An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:Exit code: 1 -
javadoc: error - invalid flag: -author".
```

Can anybody help me with this error,

**child pom**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>javadoc</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>compile</phase>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
       <verbose>false</verbose>
       <show>public</show>
       <subpackages>com.pubco.mp.emarket.services</subpackages>
       <doclet>com.sun.jersey.wadl.resourcedoc.ResourceDoclet</doclet>
       <docletArtifacts>
           <docletArtifact>
               <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
               <artifactId>wadl-resourcedoc-doclet</artifactId>
               <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
           </docletArtifact>
           <docletArtifact>
               <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
               <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
           </docletArtifact>
           <docletArtifact>
               <groupId>xerces</groupId>
               <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
               <version>2.6.1</version>
           </docletArtifact>
       </docletArtifacts>
       <additionalparam>-output ${project.build.outputDirectory}/resourcedoc.xml</additionalparam>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Parent pom :**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>javadoc</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>compile</phase>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
       <verbose>false</verbose>
       <show>public</show>
       <subpackages>com.pubco.mp.emarket.services</subpackages>
       <doclet>com.sun.jersey.wadl.resourcedoc.ResourceDoclet</doclet>
       <docletArtifacts>
           <docletArtifact>
               <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
               <artifactId>wadl-resourcedoc-doclet</artifactId>
               <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
           </docletArtifact>
           <docletArtifact>
               <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
               <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
           </docletArtifact>
           <docletArtifact>
               <groupId>xerces</groupId>
               <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
               <version>2.6.1</version>
           </docletArtifact>
       </docletArtifacts>
       <additionalparam>-output ${project.build.outputDirectory}/resourcedoc.xml</additionalparam>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Super POM : has got the version number** and am not sure how this super pom is getting downloaded .

```
<maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.5</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>

<pluginExecution>
    <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>[2.5,)</versionRange>
        <goals>
            <goal>javadoc</goal>
        </goals>
    </pluginExecutionFilter>
    <action>
        <execute/>
    </action>
</pluginExecution>
```

**full error output :**

```
1 error
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.959s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 04 18:31:07 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/29M
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.5:javadoc (default) on
project mpemarketservices-war: An error has occurred in JavaDocs
report generation:Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: -author
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was:C:\jdk1.6.0_13\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe @options
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]   
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1]
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I just add pom information, could you please have a look

Comment: actually, come to think of it, why are you using 2.5? That's stone-age material. The current version is 2.9.1 - Can you try to use it and see if the error persists?

Comment: yeah, true. But its my build manager decision. even I tried with 2.9.1 in my locally, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem today and fixed it by adding a configuration option to the Javadoc plugin:

```
<useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
```

So the resulting config looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javadoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <show>public</show>
                <subpackages>com.pubco.mp.emarket.services</subpackages>
                <doclet>com.sun.jersey.wadl.resourcedoc.ResourceDoclet</doclet>
                <docletArtifacts>
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wadl-resourcedoc-doclet</artifactId>
                        <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                        <version>${jersey-client.version}</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6.1</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                </docletArtifacts>
                <additionalparam>-output ${project.build.outputDirectory}/resourcedoc.xml</additionalparam>
                <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a doclet and you want it to be able to work with standard options, you can use `optionLength` to pass them through.

The [UmlGraphDoc](https://github.com/dspinellis/UMLGraph/blob/ff13af7ea641fb57f6ebc7d36dba11ecb71ec911/src/main/java/org/umlgraph/doclet/UmlGraphDoc.java#L32-L42) doclet shows how to forward standard options to the standard doclet while reserving ones you want for your doclet.

> ```
> import com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard;
>
> ...
>
> /**
>  * Option check, forwards options to the standard doclet, if that one
>  * refuses them, they are sent to UmlGraph
>  */
> public static int optionLength(String option) {
>     int result = Standard.optionLength(option);
>     if (result != 0)
>         return result;
>     else
>         return UmlGraph.optionLength(option);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by "doclint" which is outlined in this article:
https://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

It most often arises when using (invalid) @ or HTML java documentation.

Add this to the maven-javadoc-plugin:

```
                   <configuration>
                       <doclint>none</doclint>
                   </configuration>
```